# How to handle endianness in C

Tags: c, memcpy

I'm trying to copy `unit64_t` data to `uint8_t` array using `memcpy` as below.
But it is copying in reverse order.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<inttypes.h>
void create(uint8_t * pu8Data, uint64_t Val)
{
        uint8_t *tempBuffer = pu8Data;

        if( NULL != tempBuffer )
        {
                memcpy(tempBuffer,(const void *)&Val,8);
        }
}

int main()
{
        uint8_t *p = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*80);
        uint64_t val = 0x12345678;
        create(p,val);
        int i =0;
        for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
              printf("buffer: %d, 0x%02X\n", i, p[i]);
           }
}
```

But it is copying like below when I print.

```
buffer: 0, 0x78
buffer: 1, 0x56
buffer: 2, 0x34
buffer: 3, 0x12
```

What I was expecting was.

```
buffer: 0, 0x12
buffer: 1, 0x34
buffer: 2, 0x56
buffer: 3, 0x78
```

Comment: You are assuming on endianess. That is not the way to portable code.

Comment: Define a **proper** format for the srialised data and use proper serialisation functions. On a sidenote: on POSIX, `create` is a reserved name. The name is completely unrelated to what the functions does; always use self-explanatory names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`uint64_t val = 0x12345678;` like any other integer number, is represented in the endianess of your CPU, in this case apparently little endian. Study endianess.

To get the expected result regardless of CPU, you would have to do:

```
uint8_t val[] = {0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78};
```

Also please note that `0x12345678` is a 32 bit number, not 64 bit.